# Is rayon's parallelism limited to the cores of the machine?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I have the following toy Rust program:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::{env, thread, time};

/// Sleeps 1 second n times
fn seq_sleep(n: usize) {
    for _ in 0..n {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}

/// Launches n threads that sleep 1 second
fn thread_sleep(n: usize) {
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        handles.push(thread::spawn(|| {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000))
        }));
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}

/// Sleeps 1 seconds n times parallely using rayon
fn rayon_sleep(n: usize) {
    let millis = vec![0; n];
    millis
        .par_iter()
        .for_each(|_| thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000)));
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let n = args[1].parse::<usize>().unwrap();

    let now = time::Instant::now();
    seq_sleep(n);
    println!("sequential: {:?}", now.elapsed());

    let now = time::Instant::now();
    thread_sleep(n);
    println!("thread: {:?}", now.elapsed());

    let now = time::Instant::now();
    rayon_sleep(n);
    println!("rayon: {:?}", now.elapsed());
}
```

Basically, I want to compare the degree of parallelism of i) sequential code, ii) basic threads, and iii) rayon. To do so, my program accepts one input parameter `n` and, depending on the method, it sleeps for 1 second `n` times.
For `n` = 8, I get the following output:

```
sequential: 8.016809707s
thread: 1.006029845s
rayon: 1.004957395s
```

So far so good. However, for `n` = 9, I get the following output:

```
sequential: 9.012422104s
thread: 1.003085005s
rayon: 2.011378713s
```

The sequential and basic thread versions make sense to me. However, I expected rayon to take 1 second. My machine has 4 cores and hyper threading. This leads me to think that rayon internally limits the number of parallel threads according to the cores/threads that your machine supports. Is this correct?

Comment: I assume you know that, but you should not use `thread::sleep()` in rayon tasks.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that. Why is it not a good practice?

Comment: Exactly for the reason you observed: it is blocking other tasks from doing their work. rayon is intended for CPU-bound code. If you have I/O bound code, use an async runtime like `tokio`.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I am looking for a "busy" sleep in Rust. Ideally, I'd like to define a CPU intensive task that runs for a fixed amount of time to make sure that the OS does not preempts the task while still counting the time. I will open a new question in the next days regarding this.

Comment: @RománCárdenas "To make sure that the os does not preempts the task" Impossible without a real-time OS.

Comment: I provide more details about what I want in this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75297769/cpu-time-sleep-instead-of-wall-clock-time-sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

[`rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::build_global()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/struct.ThreadPoolBuilder.html#method.build_global):

> Initializes the global thread pool. This initialization is **optional**. If you do not call this function, the thread pool will be automatically initialized with the default configuration.

[`rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::num_threads()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/struct.ThreadPoolBuilder.html#method.num_threads):

> If `num_threads` is 0, or you do not call this function, then the Rayon runtime will select the number of threads automatically. At present, this is based on the `RAYON_NUM_THREADS` environment variable (if set), or the number of logical CPUs (otherwise). In the future, however, the default behavior may change to dynamically add or remove threads as needed.